# JSF - f:attribute boolean value

Tags: jsf, facelets, taglib

Is there a way to send boolean `f:attribute` value to the bean?

**a tag usage:**

```
<xyz:mytag isGreenColor="true" .../>
```

**facelet:**

```
<h:panelGroup binding="#{bean.field}">
<f:attribute name="isGreenColor" value="#{isGreen}"/>
</h:PanelGroup>
```

and if to send to bean how to read the attribute then - the boolean cast I mean?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send to bean like this: ()

```
<p:commandLink value="" action="#{bean.func}" process="@this">
        <f:attribute name="isGreenColor" value="#{isGreen}"/>
</p:commandLink>
```

You can use anything instead of commandLink like: p:ajax

And you can read like this:

```
public void func(ActionEvent event) {
    Boolean isGreenColor = (Boolean) event.getComponent().getAttributes().get("isGreenColor");
}
```

Comment: It is interesting but what about the tag usage case? I mean how `#{isGreen}` gets its value - the format? I mean does it needs a converter or... give more details please